# matriz simétrica c++

Tags: c++, matrices

El siguiente código retorna si una matriz es simétrica.

```
 bool is_symmetric(void) const
    {
        bool sym = true;
        for(int i = 2; i <= M_.get_m(); i++)
            for(int j = 1; j <= i - 1; j++)
                if (M_.get(i,j) != M_.get(j,i))
                    sym = false;

        return sym;
    }
```

¿por qué `i` empieza en la fila 2 (`i=2`) y `j`, como es normal, lo hace en la columna 1? ¿hay alguna restricción?

la condición de finalizado del segundo `for`, `j <= i - 1`, ¿por qué `j` siempre tiene que ser menor que `i-1`?

Comment: "*`j`, como es normal, lo hace en la columna 1*" ¿Como es normal? No veo que sea normal que los índices empiecen en 1 en [tag:c++].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matemáticas

> ¿por qué j siempre tiene que ser menor que i-1?

Porque, cuando `i = j`, `M_.get(i,j)` es igual a `M_get(j,i)`, siempre.

Lo cual también explica la primera pregunta, ya que para `i = 1`; `j` no tendría ningún valor posible (empieza por `1`, pero la condición es que sea menor o igual que `i - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0`)

Y si, `j > i`, ese valor ya está comprobado (al comprobar que `M_.get(2,4) == M_.get(4,2)`, también compruebas que `M_.get(4,2) == M.get(2,4)`.